# Visual Studio 2012. Load testing. How to determine the maximum number of virtual users?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I have 2 GB of RAM and a 1.8 GHz processor. I conduct load testing site using Visual Studio 2012. How to determine the maximum number of virtual users based on the capacity of the computer (RAM and CPU), which will be tested and the width of the Internet channel (8 megabits per second)?

Comment: I define it is only by experience

Answer (score 0):

The number of Virtual Users depends only on your tests and on the target web site.

In some tests, a virtual user needs to execute only a simple request whereas in others tests it can invoke multiple pages and services. Sometimes, the target Web Site is simply too slow.

Personnaly, I prefer to use a goal based pattern. It resembles the step pattern but adjusts the user load based on performance counter thresholds versus periodic user load adjustments. So, I generally run load tests with a CPU on the web server between 40% and 60%.